# Sort data on Data perspective (Composite C1)

Tags: c1-cms

I have created a custom datatype inside "Page Datafolders" on the "Data" perspective.
So, I have added this datafolder to a page and I am using it to show the data in the page with no problem...., but now I want to show this data sorted in admin console.

I tried to create a xml file inside of App_Data/Composite/TreeDefinitions without luck.

So, are there any tutorial to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are right to create a 'tree definition' xml file inside the ~/App_Data/Composite/TreeDefinitions folder, you should just ensure your definition has this bit:

```
<ElementStructure.AllowedAttachments ApplicationName="(your app name here)"> 
  <DataType Type="Composite.Data.Types.IPage" Position="Bottom" /> 
</ElementStructure.AllowedAttachments>
```

Once you have this defined, you can attach it to a page using the 'Attach Application' command on it.

See http://docs.composite.net/Console/Guide-to-Applications/How-to-Attach-Console-Applications for details.